# what is preventing my screensaver from kicking on? windows 10

Tags: windows-10, screensaver

I have been researching for a while on how to fix my screensaver. I can turn it on by previewing and it stays on but it wont go on by itself even though it is set to.

`powercfg /requests` tells me:

```
[DRIVER] \FileSystem\srvnet
An active remote client has recently sent requests to this machine.
```

I have tried everything from updating my network card driver to running multiple powercfg commands to try to disable it, and nothing seems to work, and nothing changes when running 
`powercfg /requests`

I'm running out of things to try to get it to work. Anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Same issue here. What about `powercfg.exe /waketimers` ?

Comment: Did you try to increase the delay, mine wouldn't kick in unless I changed the default value (which was 1 minute)